# Pub can't retrieve any Dart packages

Tags: dart, flutter

No matter which `dart` package I am trying to fetch, `pub` fails retrieving it.
When in my project root folder, I run:
`flutter packages get`

I consistently get:

`Got socket error trying to find package cupertino_icons at https://pub.dartlang.org.
pub get failed (69) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...`

Here is the output from `flutter doctor`:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (on Mac OS X 10.13.3 17D47, locale en-US, channel beta)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.2)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.0)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2017.3.5)
[!] VS Code (version 1.21.1)
[!] Connected devices
! No devices available
! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

and the `pubspec` is what comes with IntelliJ Flutter's wizard:

```
name: my_friendchat
description: A new Flutter project.

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: "0.1.1"
```

Any idea how to fix pub?

Comment: There are far to little informations here to help you. You should give as much information as possible. Logs, `flutter doctor`, and your pubspec.yaml is the minimum.

Comment: @RémiRousselet I added some details above.

Answer (score 0):

So... restarting my laptop just fixed it.